# Разница времени Date

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift3

Не могу получить значения интервала времени между двумя моментами времени, между endDate[i] и startDate[i + 1] (т.е. между остановкой и следующим стартом) и чтобы выведено было все в массив String.

```
var startDate = [String]()
endDate = [String]()
interval = [String]()
let date = NSDate()
var i = 0
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

// НАЖИМАЕМ НА СТАРТ 
i += 1
let stringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date)
startDate.append(stringDate)

// ВЫЧИСЛЯЕМ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ИНТЕРВАЛА  KAK ???????????????????????????????????????
let intervalDate = startDate[i + 1] - endDate[i]   // ??????????????????
interval.append(intervalDate)
print(interval)

//НАЖИМАЕМ СТОП
let stringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date)
endDate.append(stringDate)
```

Comment: Либо сохраняйте как timeinterval/date, либо преобразовуйте строку обратно и тогда уже вычисляйте. Либо можете написать свое решение, которое будет высчитывать разность двух строк в формате "HH:mm:ss"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, очень костыльно смотрится var i и дальнейшее ее использование. Во-вторых хранить даты и интервалы в типе String - это очень странное и плохое решение. В-третьих, startDate и endDate это массивы String, ниже вы пытаетесь их вычитать) В-четвертых используйте метод timeIntervalSinceDate.

Такое использование i и подобное обращение с индексами скорее всего приведет вас к index out of bounds exception.